# How do I store the sums of the elements in each row of a 2d array in 1d array with a function?

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, variable-length-array

I have the following task: Create a 2d array A[M][N], where M and N are inputted by the user as well the elements in each row and column. There must also be two functions:
1)The first one needs to calculate the average of all positive numbers in the 2d array. This function works just fine, at least I think so.

2)Here is where my problem is and I simply ran out of options. The second function needs to create a new array B whose elements are the sums of the elements in each row in array A. After that it needs to print out array B.

The problem is as follows: Upon inputting 2 and 2 for M and N, as well as "2" for each of the elements in the 2x2 array (I have tried with 3 everywhere too), the second function should print out array B with elements "4 4". It, however, prints out 4 and 0. When trying 3 for every prompt it printed out the first element just fine-"9" the other 2 elements should also be 9, however the program just spewed some random numbers.

The code in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
//1.
float average(int Y, int X, int A[Y][X]){
    float sum=0;
    float br=0;
    int k,r;
    for(k=0;k<Y;k++){
        for(r=0;r<X;r++){
            if(A[k][r]>0){
                
                sum+=A[k][r];
                br++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(br>0){   
    return sum/br;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}

//2.
void SumArray(int arrA[10][10], int m, int n, int B[10][1]);
int main()
{
    int i,j,M,N;
    
    printf("INPUT ROWS:\n");
    scanf("%d", &M);
    getchar();
    
    printf("INPUR COLUMNS:\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    getchar();
    int A[M][N];

    
    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
        printf("INPUT A[%d][%d]:", i,j);
        scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("ARRAY A LOOKS LIKE SO:\n");
    
    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    int B[M][1];
    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        B[i][0]=0;
    }

    //1.
    float avg= average(M,N,A);
    printf("THE AVARAGE OF ALL POSITIVE ELEMENTS IS:\n%f\n", avg);
    //2.
    printf("ARRAY B LOOKS LIKE SO:\n");
    SumArray(A, M, N, B);
    
    return 0;
}
//2.
void SumArray(int arrA[10][10], int m, int n, int B[10][1])      
{

    int i,j;
    float sum;

    for( i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        for( j = 0;j < n; j++)
        {
             sum+= arrA[i][j];              
        }
        B[i][0]=sum;
    }
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        printf(" %d ", B[i][0]);
    }
}
```

What I tried (I am a beginner when it comes to programming): Making array B a 2D array (it was 1D in the beginning), Swapping `B[10]` with `B[m]` and `B[n]`, different compilers.

Comment: You've hard-wired `SumArray` to operate on 10x10 arrays, and 10x1 arrays.  So that code will only work on arrays with those dimensions.  Why?  Why not declare the arguments the way you did in `average`?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT (all caps is shouting and considered as rude). You won't get an answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 1D array for B.

```
void SumArray(int M, int N, int A[M][N], int B[M]) {
  memset(B, 0, M * sizeof *B);
  for(int m = 0; m < M; m++)
  for(int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    B[m] += A[m][n];
}

...

int B[M];
SumArray(M, N, A, B);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `main` function, the main 2-D array with data is a VLA (variable-length array):

```
    int i,j,M,N;
    ...
    int A[M][N];
```

Your `average` is compatible with this definition:

```
float average(int Y, int X, int A[Y][X])
```

But your `SumArray` function is not compatible:

```
void SumArray(int arrA[10][10], int m, int n, ...)
```

The `SumArray` function regards the MxN array as 10x10, and this messes up all the indexing. You should make all your definitions and declarations compatible. For example:

```
void SumArray(int m, int n, int arrA[m][n], int B[m])
```

Note: to make the syntax work, you have to make `SumArray` receive the dimensions before the VLA itself.

---

Another option: declare and define all your arrays as 10x10, use only MxN elements, leaving all the others unused. In this case, you should make sure both M and N are not greater than 10 (if the user enters e.g. 11, write an error message).

This is the only option if your compiler doesn't support VLA (some compilers don't).